# convert postgreSQL column values from CAPITAL to Camel Case

Tags: postgresql, relational-database

I have two columns one have values in Camel case 'Costa Rica' which is correct but the another column is all capital 'COSTA RICA' , sometime its make problem for me while querying , Can I convert these Capital into camel case too as first column?

Answer (score 1):

Use `initcap()` function to get this done.

1. to convert all values of second column having all capital letters use below mentioned query:

```
update your_table set second_col=initcap(second_col);
```

2. if you just want to compare the columns then use like below:

```
where first_col=initcap(second_col)
```

or

```
where upper(first_col)=upper(second_col)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Rename tables
DO $$
DECLARE
    table_record RECORD;
BEGIN
    -- Loop through each table
    FOR table_record IN (SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE') LOOP
        EXECUTE FORMAT('ALTER TABLE public.%I RENAME TO %I', table_record.table_name, lower(regexp_replace(table_record.table_name, '(.)([A-Z])', '\1_\2', 'g')));
    END LOOP;
END $$;

-- Rename columns
DO $$
DECLARE
    table_record RECORD;
    column_record RECORD;
BEGIN
    -- Loop through each table
    FOR table_record IN (SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE') LOOP
        -- Loop through each column in the table
        FOR column_record IN (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = table_record.table_name) LOOP
            EXECUTE FORMAT('ALTER TABLE public.%I RENAME COLUMN %I TO %I', table_record.table_name, column_record.column_name, lower(regexp_replace(column_record.column_name, '(.)([A-Z])', '\1_\2', 'g')));
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```